# Restore DB using SMO without DATABASE is in use error

Tags: c#, sql-server, restore, smo

I am using SMO to restore the database ,

```
 ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(_serverName, _userName, _password);
 Server server = new Server(con);
 Restore destination = new Restore();
 destination.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
 destination.Database = _databaseName;
 BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(path, DeviceType.File);
 destination.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
 destination.ReplaceDatabase = true;
 destination.NoRecovery = true;
 destination.SqlRestore(server);
```

I am getting an exception message :

Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Seems quite clear to me. Set the DB to offline first, or do an online restore

Comment: thanks for the reply. i guess you meant, using KillAllprocesses method

Comment: No `Database.SetOffline()`, because `KillDatabase` will drop the database and `KillAllprocesses` kicks everyone out

Comment: SetOffline method is not working .This is the exception i recieved:" Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
ALTER DATABASE statement failed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by killing the connected processes and database

```
ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(_serverName, _userName, _password);
Server server = new Server(con);
Restore destination = new Restore();
destination.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
destination.Database = _databaseName;
BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(path, DeviceType.File);
destination.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
destination.ReplaceDatabase = true;
destination.NoRecovery = true;
server.KillAllProcesses("your db name");
server.KillDatabase("your db name");
destination.SqlRestore(server);
```